# Coinbase API returning transactions from other accounts

Tags: coinbase-api

There appears to be a problem with the Coinbase API mixing and returning transactions from both CoinBase and CoinBase Pro wallets of the same token type. I can't find a better way to report this, and supposedly Coinbase monitors this tag so let's see..

For example, I authorized the **Coinbase** API with Read access to my BTC wallet on Coinbase.  However, it is returning transactions from both my **CoinBase** BTC wallet and my **CoinBase Pro** BTC wallet (these are two different wallets/addresses).

This seems like a real problem, that the API is returning transactions from wallets it isn't supposed to..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isnt a question. Its a potential vulnerability disclosure which probably shouldnt go trough public channels.

Comment: @The Fool, this IS their official (and only) method of contact.   ‍♂️  See for yourself:  https://developers.coinbase.com/.  If you have a direct contact to somewhere at CoinBase API please let me know via PM and I'd be glad to engage in a private communication with them.

Comment: Exactly - it's NOT a security vulnerability, it's a bug.  This is their official dev support channel.  I'm following *their* requested process.  Of course it's rather weak to have Stack Overflow serve as your support system, but that's what they have done.  It's a bug, I'm reporting it.  I don't understand the downvote...  Perhaps the better option would be to simply leave these bugs unreported, and then random internet people would be happier.  "Ignorance is bliss" apparently.